# Laravel: Throw error from controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project and if I want to access `partner/X` I got `get property of non object` error, becouse I have less partners than X.

My question. How to tell the controller, that `if the result of the modelquery is empty, than throw a 404 error`?

My code is so far:

```
public function showPartner($id = 0){

   //Only allow numerical values    
  if ($id > 0){

    $partner = Partner::find($id);

    if (empty($partner)){
        return ???
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `App::abort(404, 'Record not found.');`

Comment: You can also use `findOrFail()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laravel has a specific method for that. If you use `findOrFail($id)`, it will throw an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException`, so there's no need to throw an Exception by yourself.

If you mean "show the user an 404 error" instead of literally throwing an Exception, then catch it and `abort()`:

```
public function showPartner($id = 0){

//Only allow numerical values    
    if ($id > 0){
        try {
            $partner = Partner::find($id);
            // do your work
        }
        catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            abort(404, "The Partner was not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models).

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`abort()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-abort) helper:

```
abort(404);
```

There's also  `abort_if()` and `abort_unless()` if you prefer. Whichever one you choose, you can pass it the required status code.